# BAL#401 - SENDER_NOT_ALLOWED - Not able to Join a Balancer Pool via smart contract interfacing?

Tags: solidity, web3js, decentralized-exchange, balancer

I'm looking to join a pool through a smart contract. The contract interfaces with the Balancer Vault and joins the pool, the sender would be the user and the receiver of the BPT would be the contract itself. But upon running the following function, I'm getting `BAL#401 - SENDER_NOT_ALLOWED`. I have approved both my contract as well as the vault as spenders for the ERC20 I'm using but it's not working. The following function is a slightly modified version found in the README of the interfaces directory of the `balancer-v2-monorepo`

```
function _addTokenLiquidityToBalancerPool(bytes32 poolId, address sender, uint256[] memory amountsIn, uint256 tokenIndex, uint256 minBptAmountOut) external {
        require(amountsIn[tokenIndex] > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
        (IERC20[] memory tokens, , ) = vault.getPoolTokens(poolId);
        // Use BalancerErrors to validate input
        _require(amountsIn.length == tokens.length, Errors.INPUT_LENGTH_MISMATCH);//
        // Encode the userData for a multi-token join
        bytes memory userData = abi.encode(StablePoolUserData.JoinKind.EXACT_TOKENS_IN_FOR_BPT_OUT, amountsIn, minBptAmountOut);

        IVault.JoinPoolRequest memory requests = IVault.JoinPoolRequest({
            assets: _asIAsset(tokens),
            maxAmountsIn: amountsIn,
            userData: userData,
            fromInternalBalance: false
        });
        totalDepositByUser[msg.sender] += amountsIn[tokenIndex];

        // Call the Vault to join the pool
        vault.joinPool(poolId, sender, address(this), requests);
    }
```

Is there anyone who can help? I did read somewhere that Balancer might require Relayer approval for contracts to handle funds of users ([here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136561/balancer-401-error)). Is that the case for me too based on the function?
I'm running on Goerli network.

I have tried approving both the Balancer Vault and my own contract to be spenders of the ERC20 so that they can handle it on the user's behalf.